# I can't put space between input tag

Tags: html, css

How can I put space between input tags? My page looks like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt3xv.png without spacing. I want to look like that : https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBsNt.png to be displayed in the middle of the box.

```
.enquiry {
    max-width: 1200px;
    width: 100%;
}
.form {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;   
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
} 
.clip3 {
    width: 100%;
    float:left;
    display: block;
    padding: 30px 50px;
} 
.clip2 {
    width: 33.3%;
    float:left;
    display: block;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" method="post">
    <section>
      <div class="clip2"> 
        <input class="name" type="text" value="" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
      </div>

      <div class="clip2">
        <input class="email" type="text" value="" name="email" placeholder="Email">
      </div>

      <div class="clip2">
         <input class="phone" type="text" value="" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
      </div>
    </section>

    <section>
      <div class="clip3">
        <input class="enquiry" type="text" value="" name="enquiry" placeholder="Enquiry">
      </div>
    </section>
</form>
```

Comment: If you want gap between them use margins

Comment: use margin in your css

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your *CSS* accordingly as:

### Code Snippet

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.enquiry {
  max-width: 1200px;
  width: 100%;
}
.form {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.form section {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
}
.form section::after,
.form section::before {
  content: "";
  display: table;
}
.form section::after {
  clear: both;
}
.clip2 {
  width: 33.3%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.clip2 input {
    width: 100%;
}
.clip3 {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 30px 15px;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" method="post">
  <section>

    <div class="clip2">

      <input class="name" type="text" value="" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
    </div>

    <div class="clip2">

      <input class="email" type="text" value="" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>

    <div class="clip2">

      <input class="phone" type="text" value="" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
    </div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <div class="clip3">

      <input class="enquiry" type="text" value="" name="enquiry" placeholder="Enquiry">
    </div>
  </section>
</form>
```

Comment: it is not centered : http://i.imgur.com/oZcM3ub.png  
and the enquiry input must be at max width..  http://i.imgur.com/Ipj7oOD.png

Comment: yes, it is in the middle..but the enquiry input isn't good http://i.imgur.com/WI3LDpG.png

Comment: do you have any link or something, may be in your environment there is some CSS that affecting that.

Answer (score 0):

Try its it uses the margin-left and margin-right tags to add gaps.

```css
.enquiry {
 max-width: 1200px;
 width: 100%;
 
}
.form {
 text-align: center;
 display: inline-block;
 overflow: hidden; 
 max-width: 1200px;
 margin: 0 auto;

} 
.clip3 {
 width: 100%;
 float:left;
 display: block;
 padding: 30px 50px;
 
 
} 
.clip2 {
 width: 33.3%;
 float:left;
 display: block;
 
 display: inline-block;
 
} 

input{

    margin-left:5px;

    margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" method="post">
    <section>

    <div class="clip2">
        
        <input class="name" type="text" value="" name="name" placeholder="Your Name">
    </div>

    <div class="clip2">
       
        <input class="email" type="text" value="" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>

   <div class="clip2">
   
    <input class="phone" type="text" value="" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
 </div></section>
 <section>
 <div class="clip3">
    
    <input class="enquiry" type="text" value="" name="enquiry" placeholder="Enquiry">
</div>
    </section>
</form>
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

This might help, you can change the width % to position your page in center

```
.body {
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
font-size: 100%;
width: 80%;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
padding: 2.5% 2.5% 0;
background: white;
line-height: 1.8;
border-radius: 5px;
```

}

Here 80% means 10% gap on left and 10% gap on right